# Rails form doesn't show up on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, form-for

I have a Rails app on Heroku with a couple of forms on it. They show up fine locally, but on heroku, my form doesn't show up at all. I know my database is being accessed, because I have a greeting message with a user's name at the top of the page that's displayed fine.

Has anyone run into this issue and had any luck solving it?

Comment: Which version of Rails is it?

Comment: I'm using 4.2.6

Comment: I'm wondering if I should reset my database through Heroku's dashboard?

Comment: This shouldn't have anything to do with the database. Not sure what the reason is though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your app locally on production environment and check is your form show up properly.